# Unit tests under intellij

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I am new to intellij. Trying to make the switch from Eclipse.

I have imported my project into intellij and feel that went well. The project structure follows the maven standard `src/main/java` for code and `src/test/java` for the unit tests. I then place the unit tests in the same package as the original java classes, but have directory separation for builds so my unit tests never end up in production.

I feel that I have imported the junit libraries properly because I can access them by creating a new unit test in `src/main/java` and it shows me the junit classes.

My unit tests in `src/test/java` are another matter. I am getting class not found errors on Assert and Before and also on the classes from `src/main/java` that I'm testing.

I feel like I've missed something in the setup. Please point out my error.

Comment: It's been some time since I used IntelliJ but if it's a Maven project it should be able to infer the project setup just like Eclipse does. Search for a way to tell IntelliJ that it's a Maven project and it should build the config. I don't quite know where the option for that is anymore. Sorry to be so unspecific but maybe it helps.

Comment: Not a maven project. Just follows the structure. Starting to think that might be part of the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Project Explorer you need to mark the `src/test/java` directory as a 'Test Source Root'.

To do this right-click the directory and on the popup menu you'll see an item 'Mark Directory As', which will give you the option to mark the directory as a 'Test Source Root'.

If that doesn't work, then try downloading the junit jar file and adding it manually to the dependency path.

Comment: Found that and did it. No change.

Comment: When you click on File -> Project Settings and select Modules is JUnit included under the Dependencies tab?

Comment: I had wondered if I needed to do that. Must be the directory structure that threw it off. I download the junit jar file and added it to the dependency list and that seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: To be honest, if you're following the Maven structure, it'd be easier to create a pom and let IntelliJ work with that.  You just need to create and empty project then add the pom to the Maven Projects (on the right-hand-side of the IDE), IntelliJ will do the rest plus keep it all in-sync.

Comment: @NickHolt +255 for that last comment